Using more specific datatypes in TypeScript?
Is there any way in TypeScript to write the specific datatypes instead of just umbrella number types?
For example, if I want integer type specifically returned from a function then is there any way to do it instead of:
function function_name (_params) : number {}
If there is not then what is the most suitable way to ensure that I return specific types that I want like integers of floats?
I tried this:
function function_name (_params) : int {}
but it clearly doesn't work!
one way I can think of is to ensure at the time of returning a value I can check if it is an integer by using good old '%' (modulo) but I thought there would be a cleaner way to do this so decided to ask this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79175400#comment139614230_79175400

No, there isn't a specific int type in JS (and therefore there is none in TS). But to check if a number is an integer, you can also use Number.isInteger()

This question is similar to: Is there or isn't there an integer type in JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Apologies, we have a section called Staging Ground for questions from new users designed to help them get used to the quality standards of the site. Somebody promoted your question to the main site without it being up to the standards expected of a stack overflow question, we generally try to have a smoother first run experience then what you ended up getting.

JavaScript, and by extension the TypeScript type system, does not have support for number types other than number and bigint.
For integers specifically, you can rely on TypeScript's number and bigint types to have some compile time assurances that a number is in fact an integer as demonstrated in this answer.
For a limited set of specific numbers, you can also rely on a literal union type, like for example:
type PowerOfTwo = 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16; // and so on

Another approach, that would also work for other number sub-types, is to rely on a runtime check to assert that a number is in fact of a given sub-type. You can then use a combination of nominal typing and an assertion function to convey to TypeScript that you have actually performed said check. For integers it could look like this, using Number.isInteger() as the runtime check:
type Int = number & { _brand: never };

function assertInt(n: number): asserts n is Int {
    if(!Number.isInteger(n)) {
        throw new Error(`${n} is not integer`);
    }
}

You could then use the assertion function to implement, for example, an integer division function:
function divide(dividend: number, divisor: number): Int {
    const quotient = Math.floor(dividend / divisor);

    assertInt(quotient);
    return quotient;
}

const x = divide(5, 2); // x is now of type Int

You can then also write a little wrapper function so that you can do inline checks:
function checkInt(n: number): Int {
    assertInt(n);
    return n;
}

Which you can use when calling a function that accepts Int parameters:
function multiply(multiplicand: Int, multiplier: Int): Int {
    const product = multiplicand * multiplier;

    assertInt(product);
    return product;
}

const y = multiply(checkInt(2), checkInt(4)); // y is of type Int

Playground link

TL;DR JavaScript and TypeScript have very limited support for numeric types. Differentiating between different types can mostly only be done at runtime, but nominal types and assertion functions can be used to persuade the TypeScript compiler that a number is of a certain sub-type.

As mentioned before, there is no Integer type in TypeScript. However, if you are willing to take a different approach, you can create your own custom "types" like this:
class IntegerMut {
  constructor(private value: number) {
    if (!globalThis.Number.isInteger(value)) throw new Error();
  }

  public set(value: number) {
    if (!globalThis.Number.isInteger(value)) throw new Error();

    this.value = value;
  }

  public get() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public add(value: number) {
    this.set(this.get() + value);
  }
}

class IntegerImm {
  constructor(private readonly value: number) {
    if (!globalThis.Number.isInteger(value)) throw new Error();
  }

  public get() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public add(value: number) {
    return new IntegerImm(this.get() + value);
  }
}



public set(value: number) doesn't make a lot of sense for IntegerImm - it means you need an instance in order to create a new instance from it. But the new instance is in no way related to the old one (not like, say, add() might be).

@VLAZ I'm not sure what you mean. Are you suggesting that the naming of set is not appropriate? You could give it any arbitrary name, though I agree it could be confusing if one doesn't look at the instance type. Or even remove the set method.

I mean it doesn't make sense to have an instance method that creates a new instance. const x = new IntegerImm(42); const y = x.set(43); is weird because y has nothing to do with x, yet is created from it.

Also, now I notice that it'd never terminate. set calls the constructor, the constructor calls set, set calls the constructor, the constructor calls set...etc.

You are right! I'll edit the answer. I hope this fixed it.
